# ActivityManager.getRecentTasks() returns 0 results

Tags: android

**update** I've tried this on a 1.6 AVD and a real Droid Incredible. Both have the same issue.

I need to get a list of recent tasks, but ActivityManager.getRecentTasks() always returns 0 results and can't figure out why.

```
ActivityManager result = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
ArrayList<RecentTaskInfo> apps = (ArrayList<RecentTaskInfo>) result.getRecentTasks(10, ActivityManager.RECENT_WITH_EXCLUDED);
```

I've set `android.permission.GET_TASKS` in the manifest but `apps` is always 0.

Anyone have insight in to why? I'm stumped.

Comment: Two questions: 1. What device do you use? 2. Is there something in recents when you long-press home key? I've checked your code on Nexus One, it works.

Comment: Thank you for checking. I've done it on an AVD 1.6 and on a Droid Incredible. There are things in the recent used apps. I'm stumped. I'll keep trying it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was that I needed to clean the project. Once I cleaned the project, it worked.